# How to modify colbacktitle, coltext in a tcolorbox with AAUsidebar theme?

Tags: beamer, boxes, tcolorbox, themes

I'd like to produce a presentation with beamer. I use the **AAUsidebar** theme.

I want to use my own boxes that I defined with **\newtcolorbox**. But, I can't not modify the background colour of the title (**colbacktitle**), and the colour of the text (**coltext**). Perhaps other properties are wrong.

The MVE is :

```
\documentclass[9pt]{beamer}
\usetheme[shownavsym, left]{AAUsidebar}

% If you want to change the colors of the various elements in the theme, edit and uncomment the following lines
\definecolor{mygreen}{cmyk}{0.82,0.11,1,0.25}

\setbeamertemplate{blocks}[rounded][shadow=true]
\setbeamercolor{itemize item}{fg=orange!20!black}
\setbeamertemplate{itemize item}[ball]
\setbeamertemplate{itemize subitem}[triangle]

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}

\newtcolorbox{MyBox}[1][]{
    width=\textwidth,
    colframe=red,%beamer@barcolor, % color frame:   red!75!black,
    colback=orange!50, % color background of the box
    colbacktitle=black!50!white, %beamer@barcolor!100, %beamer@barcolor, % color background of the title box    blue!85!black
    colbacklower=orange, %LimeGreen!75!LightGreen,
%   colupper=mygreen , % color of the text in the upper part
%   collower=mygreen , %  color of the text in the lower part
    coltext=mygreen!50, % color of the text (upper et lower parts)
    coltitle=mygreen!50,%mygreen!50!black, % color of the title
%   fontupper=\bfseries, %text et font avant le texte
%   fontlower=\bfseries, %text et font avant le texte 
    fonttitle=\bfseries, %text et font avant le texte
    oversize,
    left=0ex,
    right=0ex,
    top=0pt,
    bottom=0pt,
    arc=6pt,
    outer arc=6pt,
    leftrule=0pt,
    rightrule=0pt,
    toprule=0pt,
    bottomrule=0pt,
%    breakable,
    enhanced,% jigsaw,
%   title filled=true, % or false
%   rounded corners=northwest , 
    drop fuzzy shadow=black!80!white, % orange,
    title= #1}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Introduction}
  \begin{MyBox}{The title}
    \begin{enumerate}
\item my item 1
\item my item 2
\item my item 3
      \end{enumerate}
  \end{MyBox}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

What is wrong in my code ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is correct except for two little mistakes. The first one is that you declared `mybox` with one optional argument

```
\newtcolorbox{MyBox}[1][]{
```

which is empty by default. Your call to `\begin{MyBox}{Title}` leaves the title empty and considers `Title` part of your text. If you use `\begin{MyBox}[Title]` the title will be considered like this and printed as expected.

And the second one was to forget that `beamer` declares its own colors for `enumerate`, therefore, `coltext` is overwritten when you include an `enumerate` environment in you box. Normal text is written with `coltext` color, but not text in `enumerate`, `itemize` or `description`.

If you want to change all `enumerate` color text in all the document, add

```
\setbeamercolor{itemize/enumerate body}{fg=mygreen!50}
```

in your preamble. But if you just want to apply it into `MyBox`, insert it with `before upper=` in `\MyBox` declaration. This command will change how the body is typeset, but for the numbers or items you must redefine `enumerate item` or `itemize item` templates.

```
\documentclass[9pt]{beamer}
\usetheme[shownavsym, left]{AAUsidebar}

% If you want to change the colors of the various elements in the theme, edit and uncomment the following lines
\definecolor{mygreen}{cmyk}{0.82,0.11,1,0.25}

\setbeamertemplate{blocks}[rounded][shadow=true]
\setbeamercolor{itemize item}{fg=orange!20!black}
\setbeamertemplate{itemize item}[ball]
\setbeamertemplate{itemize subitem}[triangle]

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}

\newtcolorbox{MyBox}[1][]{
    width=\textwidth,
    colframe=red,%beamer@barcolor, % color frame:   red!75!black,
    colback=orange!50, % color background of the box
    colbacktitle=black!50!white, %beamer@barcolor!100, %beamer@barcolor, % color background of the title box    blue!85!black
    colbacklower=orange, %LimeGreen!75!LightGreen,
%   colupper=mygreen , % color of the text in the upper part
%   collower=mygreen , %  color of the text in the lower part
    coltext=mygreen!50, % color of the text (upper et lower parts)
    coltitle=mygreen!50,%mygreen!50!black, % color of the title
%   fontupper=\bfseries, %text et font avant le texte
%   fontlower=\bfseries, %text et font avant le texte 
    fonttitle=\bfseries, %text et font avant le texte
    oversize,
    left=0ex,
    right=0ex,
    top=0pt,
    bottom=0pt,
    arc=6pt,
    outer arc=6pt,
    leftrule=0pt,
    rightrule=0pt,
    toprule=0pt,
    bottomrule=0pt,
%    breakable,
    enhanced,% jigsaw,
%   title filled=true, % or false
%   rounded corners=northwest , 
    drop fuzzy shadow=black!80!white, % orange,
    title= #1,
    before upper={ \setbeamercolor{itemize/enumerate body}{fg=mygreen!50}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Introduction}
  \begin{MyBox}[The title]

    \begin{enumerate}
\item my item 1
\item my item 2
\item my item 3
      \end{enumerate}      
      Some text outside enumerate but inside MyBox
        \end{MyBox}

  Some text outside the box

{\setbeamercolor{enumerate item}{fg=blue}
      \begin{enumerate}
      \item Some enumerate outside MyBox
      \end{enumerate}}

      \begin{enumerate}
      \item Some enumerate outside MyBox
      \end{enumerate}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is precisely what I was looking for; many thanks! To update `enumerate item` and `itemize item` templates as @Ignasi suggested, I updated `before upper` like this:     `before upper={ \setbeamercolor{itemize/enumerate body}{fg=mygreen} \setbeamercolor{enumerate item}{fg=mygreen} \setbeamercolor{itemize item}{fg=mygreen}`